# Creating a React App for Spotify Authentication: How to Implement Login Flow with Flask Backend?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, spotipy

I am trying to authenticate user authentication through spotipy in my flask backend, which was working by itself. But when I try to introduce the front end components, it seems like the backend isn't sending the correct information OR the frontend is getting the wrong information. I tried making sure that I was sending cookies correctly from my backend, and that my cache wasn't being used to memorize whether a user was or wasn't logged in. I am very new to Web dev, especially front end so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I am expecting to happen with my code

1. Check for a cached token or user authentication state on load.
2. Redirect the user to the Spotify login if not authenticated.
3. Handle the callback from Spotify and check the authentication state.
4. Redirect back to localhost:3000/ where my frontend is hosted so it can check again, this time supposedly showing that the user has been logged in.

Here is the relevant code on my backend:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI, scope='user-read-currently-playing',
                                               cache_handler=cache_handler)
    

    if not auth_manager.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        auth_url = auth_manager.get_authorize_url()
        #print(auth_url)
        return jsonify({"logged_in": False, "auth_url": auth_url})

    spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
    user_info = spotify.me()
    return jsonify({
        "logged_in": True,
        "user_info": {
            "display_name": user_info["display_name"],
            "id": user_info["id"],
            "uri": user_info["uri"],
            "profile_url": user_info["external_urls"]["spotify"]
        }
    })

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    print(code)
    if code:
        cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
        auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI, scope='user-read-currently-playing',
                                                   cache_handler=cache_handler)
        auth_manager.get_access_token(code)
        session.modified = True
        response = make_response(redirect('http://localhost:3000/'))
        return response
    return 'Missing code parameter. Please try again.', 400
```

And here is my App.js on the frontend:

```
function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [authUrl, setAuthUrl] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/?t=${Date.now()}`;
    axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true })
      .then(response => { 
        const { logged_in, auth_url } = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
        setIsLoggedIn(logged_in);
        if (!logged_in) {
          setAuthUrl(auth_url);
          console.log('Redirecting to:', auth_url);
        }
      })  
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={!isLoggedIn ? <Login authUrl={authUrl} /> : <Navigate to="/" />} />  // Use the Login component here
            <Route path="/" element={isLoggedIn ? <SearchBar onSearch={setMessage} /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />    
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I did some testing, and in the callback function, if I redirect just back to localhost:5000, it will show me this data:

```
    "logged_in": True,
    "user_info": { etc etc...
```

Which is what I want the front end to detect. But for some reason it still picks up logged_in as false.

Answer (score 1):

When utilizing `spotipy` for the authorization code flow, you don't necessarily need to handle the callback endpoint with redirection yourself.

`Spotipy` supports several authentication flows provided by Spotify, including the Authorization Code Flow.

When `Spotipy` is described as middleware for the Authorization Code Flow, it means that `Spotipy` can handle much of the authentication process seamlessly within your Python application.

Spotipy is middleware.
So you don't necessary to handle `./callback` endpoint.

##### Demo

Back-end server by `Flask`

```py
import spotipy

from flask import Flask, session, jsonify
from flask_cookie_decode import CookieDecode
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

CLIENT_ID = '<your client id>'
CLIENT_SECRET = '<your client secret>'
REDIRECT_URI = '<your redirect uri>' # get from developer dash board
username = '<your Spotify User id>'  # get from user profile
SCOPEs = ['user-read-currently-playing', 'user-read-recently-played']

# Create the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

app.config.update({'SECRET_KEY': 'MY_SECRET_KEY'})
cookie = CookieDecode()
cookie.init_app(app)

cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                            client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                            redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI,
                            scope=SCOPEs,
                            username=username,
                            cache_handler=cache_handler)
auth_url = auth_manager.get_authorize_url()

@app.route('/get_logged')
@cross_origin()
def get_session():
    if (session and session['user']):
        return jsonify(dict(session))
    else:
        return jsonify({'logged_in': False, 'auth_url': auth_url})

@app.route('/clear_session')
@cross_origin()
def clear_session():
    session.clear()
    return jsonify({'session': 'cleared'})

@app.route('/login')
@cross_origin()
def login():
    auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                                client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                                redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI,
                                scope=SCOPEs,
                                username=username)
    if (session and session['user']):
        data = jsonify(dict(session).get('user')['user_info'])
        return data

    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
    user_info = sp.me()
    simple_user_info = {
        "logged_in": True,
        "user_info": {
            "display_name": user_info["display_name"],
            "id": user_info["id"],
            "uri": user_info["uri"],
            "profile_url": user_info["external_urls"]["spotify"]
        }
    }
    session['user'] = simple_user_info
    return jsonify(dict(session).get('user'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

##### API Testing by Postman

Clear Session

```
GET http://localhost:5000/clear_session
```

Get Logged In

```
GET http://localhost:5000/get_logged
```

Login

```
GET http://localhost:5000/login
```

**Note**- This API will only call by React

[image]

##### Front-end Code

App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/login'); // Update URL if needed
      setUserData(response.data);
      setLoggedIn(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error logging in:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {loggedIn ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Welcome, {userData?.user_info?.display_name}</h1>
          <p>ID: {userData?.user_info?.id}</p>
          <p>URI: {userData?.user_info?.uri}</p>
          <a href={userData?.user_info?.profile_url}>Profile Link</a>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>Not logged in</h1>
          <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login with Spotify</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

##### Result of Front-end

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

[image]

##### References

[How to enable CORS in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594893/how-to-enable-cors-in-flask)

[Session Example in Flask](https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-sessions/)

[flask-cookie-decode](https://flask-cookie-decode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html)

[How to get client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri and user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78130276/anyone-know-why-i-am-getting-a-403-using-the-below-code-to-remove-a-track-from-a/78131331#78131331)

[Current playlist with Spotipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76188057/current-playlist-with-spotipy/76191758#76191758)

---

#### Step 1

```py
import json
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

CLIENT_ID = '<your client id>'
CLIENT_SECRET = '<your client secret>'
REDIRECT_URI = '<your redirect uri>' # get from developer dash board
username = '<your id>'        # get from user profile
SCOPEs = ['user-read-currently-playing', 'user-read-recently-played']

auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI, scope=SCOPEs, username=username)
auth_url = auth_manager.get_authorize_url()
print('auth_url: ' + auth_url)

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
token_info = sp.auth_manager.get_cached_token()
access_token = None
if (token_info is None):
    access_token = sp.auth_manager.get_access_token()
else:
    access_token = token_info['access_token']
print('access_token: ' + access_token)

user_info = sp.me()
simple_user_info = {
    "display_name": user_info["display_name"],
    "id": user_info["id"],
    "uri": user_info["uri"],
    "profile_url": user_info["external_urls"]["spotify"]
}
print('user_info: ' + json.dumps(simple_user_info, indent=4))
```

##### Step 1 result

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! May I ask what you are setting your redirect uri to? When I try your code, it redirects me to my redirect which is: 'http://localhost:5000/callback' at the moment, and since I am not handling callback anymore, it says '404' not found

Comment: Are you redirecting to localhost:3000? When I do that, it reverts back to the not logged in page for some reason

Comment: Mine is `localhost:3000\callback`. It should be same port in your Developer configuration and running server port.

Comment: I ran flask port is 5000, mine REDIRECT URI port is 3000, react is 3000. But SpotifyOAuth takes over not necessary flask port and  REDIRECT URI port is same.

Comment: you can see this answer, how to get configuration form [your developer page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78205223/passport-spotify-accesstoken-undefined-in-session/78207581#78207581)

Comment: Ok I set my redirect in my spotify dashboard to localhost:3000\callback, as well as in my flask backend 'REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/callback'', if thats what you meant. However, when I try running, it keeps redirecting me back to the login page, and in my terminal it gives me an error indicating that my flask server hasn't been accessed? UserWarning: A cache_handler has been specified along with a cache_path or username. The cache_path and username arguments will be ignored.

Comment: Sorry it was this error:   raise SpotifyOauthError("Server listening on localhost has not been accessed")      
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Server listening on localhost has not been accessed

Comment: I added step 1 program and result, can you try it. It just test `SpotifyOAuth` without Flask.
Let me know result.

Comment: I was actually able to get it to work! But I found the only way was if I passed in the username in SpotifyOAuth(). I was wondering if there was way around having to do this each time?

Comment: The reason is, I wanted to enable users to be able to login without needing to be registered for client id on developer dashboard, but it kinda seems if thats the case, I need to allow their email in my dashboard app AND pass in their username

Comment: I think multiple users scenario is not good approach by code flow. Your case is [Client Credential Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/client-credentials-flow) is good approach even if APIs call are limited features.

Comment: I see, I was temporary able to get another email to login with some slight adjustments to your code for auth_Manager, but I have no idea how and now i don't know how to get back to it LOL

Comment: call './clear_session' by Postman then access './login' by Browser. It will back to normal.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without Postman?

Comment: browser also work. 'http://localhost:5000/clear_session'

Comment: That works. I notice that I need to login through the backend such that:
1. Go to localhost:5000/login
2. Login through Spotify
Only then does the react component work
I was wondering if there is a way to achieve (without first logging in through the backend
1. React front end detects I have not logged in, prompts me to log in
2. I am redirected and auth through spotify
3. I am then sent back to the front end with the correct session access token and what not.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea multiple users login by SpotifyOAuth() for code flow.