# passport-spotify accessToken undefined in session

Tags: express, expo, passport.js, spotify

This is an expo project that I'm working with on web. It attempts to authenticate with Spotify Web API. The access token is returned from the Spotify authentication page and is available inside the callback on req.user.accessToken.

However, in other routes called subsequently the req.user.accessToken and req.session.accessToken are both undefined. This is despite the attempt made inside the callback to assign the token to the session.

Here, the access token is available inside the authentication callback...

```
app.get(
"/auth/spotify/callback",
  passport.authenticate("spotify", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  (req, res) => {
    req.session.accessToken = req.user.accessToken;
    console.log("callback: " + req.session.accessToken);
    res.redirect("http://localhost:8081");
  }
);
```

But not in other routes

```
app.get("/spotify/get-currently-playing", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const accessToken = req.session && req.session.accessToken;
    if (!accessToken) {
      throw new Error("Access token not found");
    }
    const userData = await getCurrentSongInfo(accessToken);
    res.json(userData);
...
```

The middleware is setup earlier on as follows

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "x",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(
  new SpotifyStrategy(
    {
      clientID: "x",
      clientSecret: "x",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:5001/auth/spotify/callback",
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) => {
      // Store the access token in the session
      if (accessToken) {
        profile.accessToken = accessToken;
        console.log(profile);
        done(null, profile);
      } else {
        done(new Error("Failed to retrieve access token"));
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get from user session data

FROM

```js
app.get(
"/auth/spotify/callback",
  passport.authenticate("spotify", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  (req, res) => {
    req.session.accessToken = req.user.accessToken;
    console.log("callback: " + req.session.accessToken);
    res.redirect("http://localhost:8081");
  }
);
```

TO

```js
app.get(
"/auth/spotify/callback",
  passport.authenticate("spotify", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  (req, res) => {
    if (req.user && req.user.accessToken) {
        console.log("callback: " + req.user.accessToken);
    } else {
        console.log('callback: accessToken is none');
    }
    res.redirect("http://localhost:8081");
  }
);
```

#### Other routes also same method of access

```
req.user.accessToken
```

#### Demo code

`package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "consolidate": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.19.1",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "nunjucks": "^3.2.4",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-spotify": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

File tree

[image]

##### How to get

`client_id`, `client_secret` and `redirect_uri`

Open URL by browser

```
https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard
```

[image]

Save as `server.js` with your Client ID/secret and redirect URI.

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const SpotifyStrategy = require('passport-spotify').Strategy;
const consolidate = require('consolidate');

const CLIENT_ID = '<your client id>';
const CLIENT_SECRET = '<your client secret>';
const port = 5001; // make sure your REDIRECT_URI's port
const authCallbackPath = '/auth/spotify/callback';

const REDIRECT_URI = `http://localhost:${port}${authCallbackPath}`;


passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(
    new SpotifyStrategy(
        {
            clientID: CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: REDIRECT_URI,
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
            // asynchronous verification, for effect...
            process.nextTick(function () {
                try {
                    profile.accessToken = accessToken;
                    console.log(`accessToken is ${profile.accessToken}`);
                    return done(null, profile);
                } catch (error) {
                    return done(error);
                }
            });
        }
    )
);
const app = express();
app.use(cors()); // Enable CORS

app.use(
    session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false })
);

// Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.engine('html', consolidate.nunjucks);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.html', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    if (req.user && req.user.accessToken) {
        console.log(`In account accessToken is ${req.user.accessToken}`);
    } else {
        console.log('In account accessToken is none');
    }
    res.render('account.html', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login.html', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

// GET /auth/spotify
app.get(
    '/auth/spotify',
    passport.authenticate('spotify', {
        scope: ['user-read-email', 'user-read-private'], // you can add more scopes it depends on your require APIs call
        showDialog: false, // if set true force shows login UI
    })
);

// GET /callback
app.get(
    authCallbackPath,
    passport.authenticate('spotify', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);

// Logout route. it has a defect, I think `passport-spotify` not address it.
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout(); // No need for a callback function here
    res.redirect('/'); // Redirect to login page or any desired page
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

HTML files

`account.html`

```html
{% extends 'layout.html' %} {% block content %}
<p>ID: {{ user.id }}</p>
<p>Token: {{ user.accessToken }}</p>
<p>Profile:
    <a href=" {{ user.profileUrl }}">{{ user.profileUrl }}</a>
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

`index.html`

```html
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if not user %}
    <h2>Welcome! Please log in.</h2>
    <p><a href="/login">login</a></p>
{% else %}
    <h2>Hello, {{ user.username }}.</h2>
    <p>Your email is {{ user.emails[0].value }}</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

`layout.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Passport-Spotify Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% if not user %}
    <p>
        <a href="/">Home</a> |
        <a href="/login">Log In</a>
    </p>
    {% else %}
    <p>
        <a href="/">Home</a> |
        <a href="/account">Account</a> |
        <a href="/logout">Log Out</a>
    </p>
    {% endif %} {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

`login.html`

```html
{% extends 'layout.html' %} {% block content %}
<a href="/auth/spotify">Login with Spotify</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Result

[image]

In server terminal

[image]